# Does multiplying the inverse of two matrices give me the identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I know that B must be the inverse of A because multiplying gives the identity matrix. Im confused with the first matrix , is it a matrix A multiplied by the inverse of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first identity states that $A$ is its own inverse (such matrices are sometimes referred to as [involutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics))). So $A=A^{-1}$.

Now, if you multiply the first identity by $B$ on the left, you obtain $BA^2=B$, which can also be written $(BA)A=B$. Using the second identity, you obtain $A=B$. You could also have concluded it was the case by uniqueness of the inverse, since we had already concluded that $A$ was its own inverse.

Conclusion: $A=B=A^{-1}$.

Comment: You can also multiply the second identity on the right by $A$ to get $BAA = A$, where since $BAA = B\left(A^2\right) = B$, we likewise get $A = B$.

Comment: Agreed! That works too.